# Values of Variables Matrix NumPy

Tags: arrays, matrix, numpy, python-2.7

I'm working on a program that determines if lines intersect. I'm using matrices to do this. I understand all the math concepts, but I'm new to Python and NumPy.

I want to add my slope variables and yint variables to a new matrix. They are all floats. I can't seem to figure out the correct format for entering them. Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np

x = 2
y = 5
w = 9
z = 12
```

I understand that if I were to just be entering the raw numbers, it would look something like this:

```
matr = np.matrix('2 5; 9 12')
```

My goal, though, is to enter the variable names instead of the ints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
M = np.matrix([[x, y], [w, z]])

# or
A = np.array([[x, y], [w, z]])
```

I included the array as well because I would suggest using arrays instead of of matrices. Though matrices seem like a good idea at first (or at least they did for me), imo you'll avoid a lot of headache by using arrays. [Here's a comparison of the two that will help you decide which is right for you.](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#head-e9a492daa18afcd86e84e07cd2824a9b1b651935)

The only disadvantage of arrays that I  can think of is that matrix multiply operations are not as pretty:

```
# With an array the matrix multiply like this
matrix_product = array.dot(vector)

# With a matrix it look like this
matrix_product = matrix * vector
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you just format the string like this?:

```
import numpy as np

x = 2
y = 5
w = 9
z = 12

matr = np.matrix('%s %s; %s %s' % (x, y, w, z))
```